# Using two if statements vs. if-else

Tags: c#, if-statement

I was doing an [exercise](http://exercism.io/exercises/csharp/collatz-conjecture/readme) and wrote the following code:

```
while (n != 1) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) n = n / 2;
    if (n % 2 == 1) n = 3 * n + 1;
    ++count;
}
```

But it caused the loop to run infinitely. The trick was to remove the second if and put an else statement instead of the second if.

I cannot see why this would make any difference for my example. n is continuously decreasing down to 1, and both if-statements shouldn't be able to execute at the same time during one loop iteration.

Obviously, the if-else version logically makes more sense, since if the number isn't even, then it has to be odd. But I don't see what edge case I am missing with two ifs.

Comment: thats because after the first if, the second has the chance to execute if the n changes to be odd. In the if-else case, wont execute

Comment: The only possibilty that `n ` hits 1 (to go out of the loop) is with the first if. But then, n is odd, and will hit the second if, and will not be 1 anymore. So, when the loop body end, n will never be 1.

Comment: Sadly enough, you could have been able to figure this out with a simple debug session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's backtrack your code to see what happens.

Your loop will exit if `n == 1`.

So that means the code inside will need to assign `1` to `n` to make it exit.

We have two assignments inside, `n = n / 2` and `n = 3 * n + 1`, with criteria for when these should happen.

So let's assume the first statement ends up assigning `1` to `n`. For this to happen `n % 2 == 0` will have to be true, so let's assume `n` equals `2` when the loop starts.

`if (n % 2 == 0)` will kick in, figure out that the result is `true`, and thus execute the statement inside the `if` statement, `n = n / 2`. This will assign `1` to `n`.

But then the next if-statement comes along. Remember that `n` now equals `1`. `if (n % 2 == 1)` will now end up with a result of `true` and thus execute.

So then `n = 3 * n + 1` will execute, which will evalute to `n = 3 * 1 + 1`, or `n = 4`.

And thus `n` ends up as 4.

The **only** way to get this loop to exit is to get the following situation:

1. The first if-statement needs to execute, assigning `0` to `n`
2. The second if-statement needs to execute, assigning `1` to `n`

The only way to get the first if-statement to execute **and** assign `1` to `n` is if `n == 1` to begin with, which won't trigger that if-statement.

Therefore, there is no way this loop will ever finish, because the criteria for it doing so is just not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you reassign `n` in the first `if` which then impacts the second `if` clause. This wouldn't happen if you used an `else` because then one and only one branch would fire per loop.

A quick fix:

```
while (n != 1) {
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    n = n / 2;
  } else {
    n = 3 * n + 1;
  }

  ++count;
}
```

Since the only other possible outcome for `n % 2` is 1 then you don't need any sophisticated logic here. It's literally the only other possibility.

Comment: You missed the `++count;`